# How to set zeromq send message block?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

How to configuration parameters that `zeromq` can Send a  block message，

When a process sends a message to another process，

if another process does not receive the message, the process which send message will block on the `send` function  does not `return`

Comment: https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/client_server.html

Comment: I would suggest you read something about the actual technology before you ask here on Stack Overflow... http://zguide.zeromq.org/

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest REQ-REP socket pattern; check the ZeroMQ Guide "Hello World" example.

Comment: it is not so simple,if you have one rep server and has many req client ,the rep sever send repsonse message , and then recv a req request from another client,you can't know if the first req client if recv the rep message

Comment: @python Read's the guide, you've skipped far ahead and missed some important details.